# Add action column in table where action row are from ng-content

Tags: angular

I created shared component for table where I can pass headers and data, so I can use it in my multiple other components.

Now the scenario is in one component I want an `Edit` button in each row and in second component I want `Active/Inactive` radio button, so I use `<ng-content>` but it will added to only last row of the table.

Here is sample code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mvcbrk

Comment: better to create set of action like radio button, button , checkbox and then you pass respective behaviour to component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children passed by the parent can only projected once (no matter how many `<ng-content>` are there).

So in this case you have to use `<ng-template>` and `TemplateRef` and `ContentChild`

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wuqgtn

Like this

**app.component.html**

```
<app-my-table [headers]="headers" [bodies]="bodies">
   <ng-template>
       <button (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
   </ng-template>
</app-my-table>
```

**my-table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-table',
    templateUrl: './my-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-table.component.css']
})
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<Element>; // Added this line and its import
    @Input() headers: string[];
    @Input() bodies: string[][];
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

**my-table.compnent.html**

```
<td>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef">
    </ng-container>
    <!-- <ng-content></ng-content> -->
</td>
```

Comment: Kenny, use *ngTemplateOutlet to allow pass as argument the line or the object, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eokbis?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmy-table%2Fmy-table.component.html